# How to integrate a working index page as kendo window modal pop up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am stuck in the following scenario: I have two screens, lets name it screen1 and screen2, which have its own index page and controller. The two screens works fine when open through browser with independent URL(example to access screen1 just type in browser mydomain/screen1). Now I want to show screen2 as kendo modal popup in screen1 on click of a button. How to achieve this?

Remember screen2 may also be accessed independently by in URL mydomain/screen2. I am using asp.net MVC framework.

Comment: It should be like a common popup, just use the [`content`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-content) parameter as a url pointing to your screen2 Action(can be used as a Partial too). What did you tried?

Comment: I tried writing a method which will return a partialview of the required view and then in my js I am rendering it as html in a Div of parent window then intiliazing and opening the Div as kendow window. Everything works but javascript function in document ready of child window don't get triggered

Comment: Yeah, that won't happen and it is right, cause the document already was *ready* before. What you can do is to wrap everything that is on your ready event in a function, call that function in the document ready, and when open the window, call the function too.